# SBCL - Package lock all Quicklisp libraries as they are loaded?

Tags: package, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, quicklisp

Can I automatically package-lock libraries as they are loaded by Quicklisp? I want every package locked. Can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To lock all existing packages just call:

```
(dolist (package list-all-packages)
  (sb-ext:lock-package package))
```

Comment: It would be interesting to package-lock libraries *as* they are loaded, so you could see which libraries step on each other during loading. Unfortunately, I don't know any good way to do that.

Comment: @Xach how about defining an after method for asdf:operate that specializes on load-op. Computing the difference between the previous list of packages and the current one?

Comment: It seems like only one person could do that. What if someone wanted more than one after method?